# How to optimize performFiltering on a large list in android?

Tags: java, android, list, filter

I have implemented my own custom performFiltering function. It works fine with small data set, but now as my database grown to a big number, this is taking too much time and i can't show user very responsive UI because of it. Any suggestion on how to optimize this?

```
@Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence chars) {
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if (chars != null && chars.length() > 0) {
            String mask = chars.toString();
            List<String> keptObjects = new ArrayList<String>();

            // On debugging through DDMS, below loop is taking most time.
            for (String object : listToApplyFilter) {
                if ((object.toLowerCase()).startsWith(mask.toLowerCase()))
                    keptObjects.add(object);
            }
            result.count = keptObjects.size();
            result.values = keptObjects;
        } else {
            result.values = listToApplyFilter;
            result.count = listToApplyFilter.size();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If the filtering really takes a long time, don't do this in the UI thread, but make a separate thread instead.

Comment: ahh .. this doesn't came in my mind. This solved my problem a bit (using AsyncTask), but still need to wait until this filtering is being done. Any way to optimize this code. Thanks for pointing this out.